# How to transform multi-label to multi-class in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, scikit-multilearn

Let's say I have the following samples with their respective multi-label

Where `X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6` are samples

and `Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4` are labels

```
X1 : {Y2, Y3}
x2 : {Y1}
X3 : {Y2}
X4 : {Y2, Y3}
X5 : {Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4}
X6 : {Y2}
```

How do I transform to

```
X1 : y1
x2 : y2
X3 : y3
X4 : y1
X5 : y4
X6 : y3
```

What I understood is that this approach is how the transformation happens in the Label Powerset method. But, I do not want to classify using this method. I just wanted to convert the labels.

We gave `MultiLabelBinarizer` to convert the multi-label to two-class. But this one only creates 0 and 1.

Comment: Can you give a detail of what are the objects y1 and Y1, what types ?

Comment: ``X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6`` are samples and ``Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4`` are labels

Comment: what's the motivation behind the transformation. Are you just assigning the labels randomly?

Comment: @OlasimboArigbabu The purpose is to transform multi-label classification problems into multi-class classification problems. This is similar to the Label Powerset method. But, I just wanted to convert the labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to map sequences of labels to a new label, you could convert those sequences to their string representation and use the `LabelEncoder` from `sklearn`.

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

Y = [(1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1,)]

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit([str(y) for y in Y])

le.transform([str((1,)), str((1, 2))])
>>> array([2, 0])
```

Do be wary though, any invalid sequence in your test set won't be supported by your label encoder. This suggestion assumes labels are ordered in their representation and non-repeating.

Comment: Can this method make the same multi-label be the same value? For example, let's say X1 with label {y1,y2} and X3 with label {y1, y2} too. Both of them have the same label let's say label Z1. Is this possible?